# Statistics question: how do I use standard deviation in this case?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

$y$ is a function of $a, b$ and $c.$

I have data for a, b and c over a period of time.

I am plotting a graph of $y$ against time. At the time $= t_{\text{lost}}$, I start to lose all $c$ values. How do I apply the past standard deviation of $c$ to predict the $y$ values beyond $t_{\text{lost}}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "I lose all $c$ values"? Do you mean that they become zero?

Comment: Is $c$ a random variable ?

Comment: @MattiP. I am processing a list of available data in this format: time, a, b and c. I am using a, b and c to calculate y, because I wanted to plot y against time. However, after certain 'time', I have only got time, a and b; while c value is corrupted / lost / not reasonable. I am trying to do a sensitivity study to show possible max / min range of the c values against time when c is not available. I hope this makes it clearer. If you don't mind, please read my reply to Yves below as well. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No. I have given a, b and c for a period of time, let's say day 1 to 50. However, at day 12 and beyond, c values become unreliable. I am trying to use the c value from day 1 to 11, when it was reliable, to predict the y (calculated using combination of a, b and 'c') for day 12 and beyond. Hope this explains.

Comment: So `a`,  `b` and `y` play no role in the question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think you are right. I confused myself. I guess if I can predict the c values, y calculation will be straight forward. You are right. I just need to know how best to predict c. For example, add/minus 3 standard deviation (sigma). Do I add/minus 3 sigma of the available c values to the last available c value, and always add/minus 3 sigma to the previous calculated c value?

Comment: What is the rationale of adding/subtracting the deviation ? Note that by doing this iteratively, you will end-up with a very large interval.

Comment: @YvesDaoust To provide confidence that most likely c is within this max / min range.

Comment: Why are you handling $c$ as if it was a random variable when it is not ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are right. I guess I am trying to achieve the following:

- to show that the change in c has minimal impact on y;

- ideally, to use the values of a and b, and past relationship between a, b and c to predict possible value of c when c is not available using trend of a and b. 

If it is too complicated, achieving the first point is good enough.

Comment: I asked you if $a$ and $b$ played no role. And now it seems that you expect them to be correlated with $c$ !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I have the feeling that you are trying to extrapolate the variable $c$ from a number of samples.

Extrapolation by an interpolation method such as the Lagrange polynomial will miserably fail, and unless you have a reasonable explanatory model for $c$, anything will fail with such a large extrapolation range.

Your only luck is to have a good parametric model for $c$, fit the model on the available data, and pray.

Comment: Thank you and I have given you an upvote (it doesn't show publicly because my account is new).

Comment: It's unclear why you believe this won't work, when we have so few details about the problem. Suppose our function is $y = 1000a + 100b + 0.01c$, the value of $c$ is almost irrelevant in determining $y$. You could plug in your entire range of previously seen values for $c$, and still get a very narrow range of potential $y$ values. If $c$ doesn't vary much in the first place, you can just plug in mean values for a pretty successful interpolation.

Comment: @NuclearWang: if the influence of the variations of $c$ is minute, there is no point even discussing this. My point is that long range extrapolation does not work.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't know how you can state that unequivocally when we don't know anything about $c$ or its predictability. 10 days of data might be enough to accurately predict $c$ over the next 40 days. It might not be, but I don't understand the a priori assumption that one shouldn't even bother with extrapolation.

Comment: @NuclearWang Thank you. I wonder if you have a suggestion on how to confirm the influence of c is small? Anyhow I am already getting a lot clearer picture of way forward from you both. Thank you again.

Comment: @NuclearWang: read my answer. If you have a predictive model, fit it. If you don't, drop it.

Comment: Thank you @YvesDaoust again. In the meantime I am trying to learn more about c and its influence on y. To help provide detail exactly what are a, b, c and y, if useful, a, b and c measures strain (change in length) at the same location, but in three directions. I needed all three values to compute a force, y. I am not familiar either with how they relate to each other, but I am guessing from the trend of how they related to each other, the same relationship will be true when c is N/A. I can see now (esp. from your answer) that learning more about c will help. I will try to do that.

Comment: @user13319591: you can rely on the sensitivity coefficient, computed as the relative variation of $y$ over the relative variation of $c$, and of course on the variations of $c$. But by just peeking at your data it should be obvious if the influence is serious or not !

Comment: @YvesDaoust what you said about sensitivity coefficient sound exactly like what I needed. Can I get some reference if that is possible?

Comment: @user13319591: lookup this expression. But common sense is equally effective.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you!